# 1 Entity with 2 references to the same table. Change the entities names?

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity with 2 references to the same table. When i make an instance, entity framework automatic instance 2 entities of the second table with the same name + 1 or 2. I want to change the name of the 2 automatic instances programmatically, it is possible?. I don't want to change the Model, because in future, maybe, i will have to regenerate the model and changes made on this will be lost.

Sorry for my poor english

```
Example:

SQL Tables:

    **Table People**
    ID_People
    Name
    Address

    **Table XXX**
    ID_Customer (FK to People)
    ID_Seller (FK to People)

Automatic Entities:

    **Entity for Table XXX**
    ID_Customer (FK to People)
    ID_Seller (FK to People)
    People1
    People2

I Want :

    **Entity for Table XXX**
    ID_Customer (FK to People)
    ID_Seller (FK to People)
    Customer (Instance of people for ID_Customer)
    Seller (Instance of people for ID_Seller)
```

Answer (score 0):

No you should change the model. You can't dynamically change names of navigation properties. Moreover if you change names in designer (EDMX - CSDL) these changes will not be lost after updating from database.

Comment: Yes, but if I remove the table and then reinsert, the changes will lost :(   Thanks any way

Comment: Yes but removing table (deleting entity from model) is rather rare situation.